# Force ggplot gradient to include low colors that are < 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have a plot as this.

```
data <- data.frame(
  name=seq ( 1, 15),  
  value=c( 4.5,  21.1,  32.8 ,  8.1, -44.1 ,-27.7 , -1.5 ,148.0, -30.6 ,143.5, 486.0,  58.5, 226.0 , 4.6  ,43.5 )
)


ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value, fill = value )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(mid="orange", low = "red", high = "green", midpoint = -1 )
```

I would like all the lowest values and also < 0 to be red however in this plot here the lowest color its showing looks like orange. Is there anyway to force ggplot to include red for the lowest value, bonus would be great that its condition only if its < 0.  In other words if the range was only from 0-100 then it should just be orange to green.  Is this possible? thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by setting `breaks` argument: (Play around)

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value, fill = value )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green", name="Sum", 
                      labels = c("0", "500"),
                      breaks = c(0, 400))
```

[image]